# App Packaged With Pyinstaller Loses Write Permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have an app that downloads content and saves it to the hard drive under a user specified path.  This app also creates a save file via python's shelve module in its own directory.  Everything works perfectly until Pyinstaller is used to package the app.  Once the app is packaged, it will no longer save to the path that has been specified if it is not in the Downloads folder.

To add one more layer to this problem, once the application package located in the Pyinstaller created 'dist' folder is zipped and extracted, it will no longer create or save to the save file created by shelve unless the application folder is moved to the Downloads folder.

This is the code that saves the downloaded files:

```
def run(self):
    response = requests.get(self.url, stream=True)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            with open(self.filename, 'wb') as file:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
                    file.write(chunk)
```

And the code that loads the save file:

```
@classmethod
def load_pickled_state(cls):
    with shelve.open('save_file', 'c') as shelf:
        # load items
```

It is packaged using Pyinstaller's one directory option.  I have checked the folder properties and they are telling me that I do have write permission.

Why would packaging the app with Pyinstaller affect write permissions and why would zipping and extracting the executable package affect these permissions even further?

Comment: As a wild guess: do you use `__file__` attribute somewhere in the code?

Comment: @9dogs No, `__file__ ` isn't used anywhere.

Comment: This is not a solution, but I have worked around the save file problem by saving all data files to the AppData folder on Windows.  What is posted above does not seem to be an issue on Linux.