# How can I solve a PermissionError, raised when I save a file using PyInstaller in a given directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a problem in an app I created using PyInstaller. I want to create a report on excel using openpyxl, then I save it in a directory I choose using tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory() comand. Everything works perfectly when I run the code from Spyder, but when I create an .exe app using PyInstaller it all runs correctly until the line where the excel file is saved,

```
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import os
import openpyxl as opxl

wk = opxl.Workbook()
...
#More code
...
file = 'Report.xlsx'
#If I comment the next two lines, there is no Error in the .exe app
root = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Where do you want to save '+file+'?') 
file = os.path.join(root, file)
wk.save(file) #Here is where the error is raised
```

where a PermissionError [Errno 13] is raised.

The funny thing is that I don't have this issue if the tkinter command isn't used and the file is saved in the same directory where the .exe file is.

My pyinstaller command was:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --onefile --name "C:\\blablabla" "root\\my_code.py"
```

My spec file is:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['root\\my_code.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\blablabla'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='exe_file_name',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

I have seen other people having this kind of issue and it looks that it is a Windows problem, but I haven't found an useful answer so far:

[App Packaged With Pyinstaller Loses Write Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267331/app-packaged-with-pyinstaller-loses-write-permissions)

Update: I tried adding the option "--uac-admin", but it neither works. I have the suspicion I need to add a manifest, but not 100% sure nor how to create it.

Thanks beforehand.